# how to insert the searched string into new row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel containing a specific set of data for Example :

```
Sno String
1   ram has a ball
2   karan has a ball
3   raj has a ball
4   seema has a ball
5   raj has a ball   raj
```

From the above df i want to extract specific set of names and write them to new column

```
Sno String           names  count
1   ram has a ball   ram    1
2   karan has a ball karan  2
3   raj has a ball   raj    3
4   seema has a ball
5   raj has a ball   raj    4
```

The Code Which i am using :

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.read_excel (r'<path>')

array = {'ram','karan','raj'}
count = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   sql = row["string"]
   for i in array:
       str = re.findall(i,sql)
       if str:
           count = count + 1
       else :
           continue
       df["name"] = pd.Series(str)
       df["count"] = pd.Series(count)
       
path_to_file = r'<path>'
df.to_excel(path_to_file)
```

Code is working but it's iterating over only a single row instead of writing the row value for each iteration

The Output which i am getting :

```
Sno String           names  count
1   ram has a ball   ram    1
2   karan has a ball 
3   raj has a ball   
4   seema has a ball
5   raj has a ball
```

Can anyone help me with my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `str.findall` from `pandas`

```
df['names'] = df.String.str.findall('|'.join(array)).str[0]
df['cnt'] = df.names.notna().cumsum().mask(df.names.isna())
df
Out[176]: 
              String  names  cnt
0     ram has a ball    ram  1.0
1   karan has a ball  karan  2.0
2     raj has a ball    raj  3.0
3   seema has a ball    NaN  NaN
4  raj has a ball       raj  4.0
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response It worked perfectly ! I had just one question can you please tell me how code is working without any looping statements.

Comment: @shubhamkumar pandas is vectorized package , most of loop function here can be done without it :-)

Comment: Okay ! Understood 
it's picking up the first occurrence of strings inside an array and writing it to the row lets say i have multiple occurrence  like i have this statement in a single row ` ram has a ball   ram   karan has a ball  ram has a ball ` the expected output should be ` Ram Karan ` but i am getting the first word only it's skipping the rest of the string

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
df['String'].str.findall('|'.join(array)).map(lambda x: x[0] if x else '')
```

output:

```
0      ram
1    karan
2      raj
3         
4      raj
```

full code:

```
df['names'] = df['String'].str.findall('|'.join(array)).map(lambda x: x[0] if x else '')
df['count'] = (~df['names'].eq('')).cumsum().mask(df['names'].eq(''), '')
```

output:

```
   Sno                String  names count
0    1        ram has a ball    ram     1
1    2      karan has a ball  karan     2
2    3        raj has a ball    raj     3
3    4      seema has a ball             
4    5  raj has a ball   raj    raj     4
```

Answer (score 1):

problem is these two lines:

```
df["name"] = pd.Series(str)
df["count"] = pd.Series(count)
```

instead putting them into the loop, it is better that you init two lists before for loop, and append to list within loop, and insert to df after the loop, something like this:

```
# before the loop
name_list = []
count_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # do somthing and get current name and count
    name_list.append(name)
    count_list.append(count)

# add series to df
df['name'] = pd.Series(name_list)
df['count'] = pd.Series(count_list)
```

iterating rows like this can be slow, if you need a faster solution, think about vectorizing the operations mentioned in other answers